# 16.04 therubyracer/v8 loaderror v8.so 4

Tags: therubyracer

I am using Rails 4.2.5, ruby 2.2.5, v8 and the rubyracer gem tried all kids of versions from on-line helps nothing works. . I keep getting the errors below. V8 is not able to initialize. I tried different versions of rails and ruby using rvm. Bundle installs and bundle updates have no errors at all. Then when I 'rake' I get the following errors 'not happening' on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
rake
rake aborted!
LoadError: incompatible library version - /home/wayne/.rvm/gems/ruby-    2.2.5/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8/init.so
/home/wayne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8.rb:4:in `require'
/home/wayne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/wayne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2       /lib/therubyracer.rb:1:in `require'
/home/wayne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2       /lib/therubyracer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: have you tried reinstalling V8? it looks like the version you have installed isn't compatible with 16.04?

Comment: I have the same problem, how can I fix this anyone?

Comment: This fixed the problem for me Ubuntu 16.04, Rails 4.2.5, Ruby 2.2.5, PG 9.4  sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install build-essential